# Azure Elastic SQL server Pool with database pricing

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have one question as I am bit confuse about pricing of Elastic pool with existing database.
I am considering below scenarios.

1) I have created 3 database with standard pricing tear.

2) I have created Elastic pool with Standard pricing tear and include all the created database in this pool.

my confusion is Do I need to pay for 3 database as well as Elastic pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to pay separately for the databases included in the elastic pool. You only pay for the elastic pool based on the allocated eDTUs for that elastic pool. All the included databases in that pool share those set of eDTUs. SQL database [pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) page provides more details on elastic pool pricing tiers.

-- Srini

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it really helpful to understand the concept. I have one more confusion that elastic database pool allows us to associate existing database inside that. now if I already have database and now I created the elastic pool and add those existing database. do i need to pay for those database or now it will include as a part of elastic pool price.